# Apex Test - Trying to get a simple null check over 80%

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I have a simple Apex test class that checks for a field. If it doesn't find a value return null.

```
    @AuraEnabled
    public static string GetAreaPath(string supportProductName) {
    List<Support_Product__c> areaPaths = [select ADO_Area_Path__c from Support_Product__c where Support_Product_Name__c = :supportProductName limit 1];
    
    if (areaPaths.isEmpty()) {
         return null;
     }
    
    return areaPaths[0].ADO_Area_Path__c;
}
```

When I try to write a test for it. I can never get it to hit the null line. It never gets above 80%. I need at least 85% for coverage.

```
    @isTest
private static void TestGetAreaPath(){
    Support_Product__c tProd = new Support_Product__c(
        Name = 'TestProd',
        ADO_Area_Path__c = 'TestPath'
    );
    insert tProd;

    Support_Product__c noPath = new Support_Product__c(
        Name = 'TestProdNoPath',
        ADO_Area_Path__c = null
    );
    insert noPath;

    DevelopmentIntegrationController devInt = new DevelopmentIntegrationController();
    string sProdName = 'TestProd';
    
    Test.startTest();
    string sProd = DevelopmentIntegrationController.GetAreaPath('TestProd');
    string nProd = DevelopmentIntegrationController.GetAreaPath('TestProdNoPath');
    Test.stopTest();        
    System.assertEquals(sProd, 'TestPath', 'paths found');
    System.assertNotEquals(null, sProd, 'no paths found');
}
```

How can I structure the test to touch that null value.

Comment: You should break this up into two tests (one for when you do find a record, one for when you don't). Keeping them separate helps keep tests simpler and easier to read, and can help you identify issues sooner (a failure in one test doesn't prevent other tests from running. Mashing two test methods into one will mean you don't get to the second "test"). Also, based on what you've shared so far, both of your calls to `GetAreaPath()` should return null because you never set `Support_Product_Name__c` in your test records. Is there a trigger or a flow you have that is setting that field on insert?

Comment: Thanks Derek F for responding.  I moved the two tests into their own methods. But the code coverage marks 'return null;' in red still. 
The field name is 'Support_Product__c.Name' not 'Support_Product__c.Support_Product_Name__c'.

Comment: The "make it two tests" bit was just general style/guidance. Doing that alone can never fix a failing test (unless it was an issue of governor limits, I suppose). I also got `Support_Product_Name__c` from the query you provided (`from Support_Product__c where Support_Product_Name__c = :supportProductName`). So you either have a typo in your code or made a mistake in reproducing it here.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this code:

```
Support_Product__c noPath = new Support_Product__c(
    Name = 'TestProdNoPath',
    ADO_Area_Path__c = null
);
insert noPath;
```

This way, your query won't return a value. Your last line of code:

```
System.assertNotEquals(null, sProd, 'no paths found');
```

Should be:

```
System.assertEquals(null, nProd, 'no paths found');
```

In order to confirm that the null value we expect was received.

Also, in the general sense, I try to write methods that have no branches:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static string GetAreaPath(string supportProductName) {
    String result; // default value is null for a variable
    for(Support_Product__c areaPath: [select ADO_Area_Path__c from Support_Product__c where Support_Product_Name__c = :supportProductName limit 1]) {
    result = areaPath.ADO_Area_Path__c;
    }
    return result;
}
```

As you gain experience developing, you can find a lot of tricks like this to reduce code complexity.

Comment: Thank you sfdcfox, that got it.